# Cannot upgrade Samsung gt-i5800 firmware from 2.1

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-apollo

Hi I cannot upgrade Samsung gt-i5800 firmware from 2.1 using kies, it tells me that the phone requires 3000 mb (or 3gb) but it doesn't even have this as internal memory as far as i know!

Has anyone else had this problem?

Also the storage space is always getting full and won't save on my external sd card - will the update change that?

Any help would be great as I don't know what I'm doing and I'm sick of a phone that can only have 5 extra apps or so on top of the ones it comes with :(

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is via Kies and relates to the PC that is running the Kies - it checks to see if you have 3GB of space on it (do not know why). It does not relate to the space on the phone internal memory.